# Angular 8 CRUD With OAuth2.0 In WebAPI fails with error: "unsupported_grant_type"

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, oauth, iis-express, webapi

I am trying to set up an OAuth login, with WebApi 2, using the Angular 8 CRUD With OAuth2.0 In WebAPI (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-8-crud-with-oauth2-0-in-webapi-part-2/) article.

I have pretty much cut and pasted his code but I am getting:

*400 (Bad Request) Error: "unsupported_grant_type"*

when I make the call back to my Visual Studio 2015 IIS express instance with, http://localhost/oauth/token

I have run through a dozen or so articles, which all say to include the content-type header of application/x-www-urlencoded, which I have done and I still can't get this bloody thing to work!

He has his user authentication is a service, which looks like this:

```
import {HttpClient,HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';    
import { ProductDTO } from '../app/ProductDTO';    
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';    
@Injectable({    
  providedIn: 'root'    
})    
export class ProductService {    
  ApiUrl='http://localhost:57046/';    
  constructor(private httpclient: HttpClient) { }    

  UserAuthentication(UserName: string,Password: string):Observable<any>{    
   let credentials='username=' +UserName  + '&password=' +Password +'&grant_type=password';     
   var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencoded','No-Auth':'True' });    
  return this.httpclient.post<any>(this.ApiUrl+'token',encodeURI(credentials),{headers:reqHeader});    
  }    
}
```

With the backend that is receiving the OAuth request being:

```
public class UtiliAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        private const string IPW = "invalid_password";
        private const string IPWC = "invalid_password_recaptcha";

        public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            string clientId;
            string clientSecret;
            string jwtName = context.Parameters.Get(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebJWTName"]);

            if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
            {
                context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
            }

            if (context.ClientId == null || jwtName.Equals(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebJWTProg"]))
            {
                context.Validated(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AudienceId"]);
            }
            else
            {

                if (context.ClientId == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "client_Id is not set");
                }
                else
                {

                    if (AudienceProvider.FindAudience(context.ClientId) == null)
                    {
                        context.SetError("invalid_clientId", $"Invalid client_id '{context.ClientId}'");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.Validated();
                    }
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CORSUrl"] });

            ApplicationUserManager userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            UtiliUserModel user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                UtiliUserModel failUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);

                if (failUser == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("user_not_found", "Please check your user name and try again.");
                    return;
                }

                await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(failUser.Id);

                if (await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(failUser.Id))
                {
                    ContextSetErrorLockOut(context);
                    return;
                }

                int attemptsLeft = userManager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout - failUser.AccessFailedCount;

                context.SetError(attemptsLeft == 1 ? IPWC : IPW, $"Incorrect password. You have {attemptsLeft} attempt{(attemptsLeft > 1 ? "s" : "")} left before account is locked out.");
                return;
            }

            if (await userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
            {
                ContextSetErrorLockOut(context);
                return;
            }

            if (user.AccessFailedCount > 0) await userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);

            IFormCollection formData = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, "JWT");
            oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebJWTName"], formData[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebJWTName"]]));
            oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScopeClaim"], new UtiliportalViews(null).IsCurrentRoleAnyAdmin(context.UserName) ? ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScopeClaimAdmin"] : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScopeClaimUser"]));
            context.Validated(new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string> {{ UtiliportalDbConstants.AudiencePropertyKey, context.ClientId ?? string.Empty }})));
        }

        private static void ContextSetErrorLockOut(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            context.SetError("locked_out", "This account has been locked.");
        }
    }
```

This backend has been working for years, with no problems with the current AngularJS client. Now trying to rewrite the site into Angular 8, causes this nonsense.

Can someone please post a working example of how to call an OAuth/WebApi 2.0 login token, using a Visual Studio IIS Express server.

Answer (score 0):

The following code sends an oAuth 2 password grant type with client id and secret to a dotnet core 3 server configured with JWT token generation using OpenIddict library.

Try this in your auth service in Angular:

```
export interface JWT {
    token_type: string;
    access_token: string;
    expires_in: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    private api = `${environment.serverURL}/connect/token`;
    private clientID = `${environment.clientID}`;
    private secret = `${environment.secret}`;
    private currentTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<JWT>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    login(email: string, password: string): any {
        const payload = new HttpParams()
            .append('grant_type', 'password')
            .append('redirect_uri', 'http://localhost:4200')
            .append('client_id', this.clientID)
            .append('client_secret', this.secret)
            .append('scope', 'email profile roles')
            .append('username', email)
            .append('password', password);
         return this.http.post<JWT>(this.api, payload).pipe(map(token => {
             localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token));
             this.currentTokenSubject.next(token);
         }));
    }
}
```